Hide WooCommerce shipping methods based on the variation product attribute
I'm trying to hide WooCommerce shipping methods based on variations chosen by the user.
I have a product attribute named "Versione" and used for variations. This attribute has two terms with slug: "digitale" and "cartaceo".

I would like to hide free_shipping:5 and flat_rate:3 shipping method rate IDs, when a product variation with "digitale" attribute term, is in cart.

I would like to hide free_shipping:4 shipping method rate ID, when a product variation with "cartaceo" attribute term, is in cart.


I've come across this code:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'ts_hide_shipping_method_based_on_variation_product_attribute', 10, 2 );
function ts_hide_shipping_method_based_on_variation_product_attribute( $rates, $package ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // HERE define the Product Attibute taxonomy (starts always with "pa_")
    $taxonomy = 'pa_versione'; // Example for "Color"

    // HERE define shipping method rate ID to be removed from product attribute term(s) slug(s) (pairs) in this array
    $data_array = array(
        'flat_rate:3' => array('digitale'),
        'free_shipping:4' => array('cartaceo'),
    );

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $cart_item ){
        if( isset($cart_item['variation']['attribute_'.$taxonomy]) ) {
            // The product attribute selected term slug
            $term_slug = $cart_item['variation']['attribute_'.$taxonomy];

            // Loop through our data array
            foreach( $data_array as $rate_id => $term_slugs ) {
                if( in_array($term_slug, $term_slugs) && isset($rates[$rate_id]) ) {
                    // We remove the shipping method corresponding to product attribute term as defined
                    unset($rates[$rate_id]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}

But It doesn't work. Where I'm wrong?
PS. My code is based on Hide WooCommerce shipping methods based on product attributes not used for variations answer code.

You were near… Assuming that "Versione" is a global product attribute (not a local custom product attribute created at product level), try the following replacement code:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_method_based_on_variation_product_attribute', 10, 2 );
function hide_shipping_method_based_on_variation_product_attribute( $rates, $package ) {
    // Data array of product attribute term slug and shipping rate ID(s)  (pairs)
    $data = array(
        'digitale' => array('flat_rate:3', 'free_shipping:5'),
        'cartaceo' => array('free_shipping:4'),
    );
    $taxonomy = 'pa_versione'; // The targeted product attribute taxonomy (always starts always with "pa_")
    $terms_found = array(); // Initializing

    // Loop through cart items for this shipping package
    foreach ( $package['contents'] as $item ){
        // Check for related product attributes set for variation
        if( isset($item['variation']['attribute_'.$taxonomy]) ) {
            $terms_found[] = $item['variation']['attribute_'.$taxonomy]; // Found: add the term slug to the array.
        }
    }

    if ( ! $terms_found ) { // If no product attribute is found, exit.
        return $rates;
    }

    // Loop through attributes terms found
    foreach ( $terms_found as $term_slug ) {
        if( isset($data[$term_slug]) ) {
            // Loop through shipping methods rate IDs defined for the current product attribute term
            foreach ( $data[$term_slug] as $rate_key ) {
                // If the current defined shipping method is availaible
                if( isset($rates[$rate_key]) ) {
                    unset($rates[$rate_key]); // Remove it
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.
Important: You will have to empty your cart to refresh shipping methods cache.

I've created the attribute globally by going to Products --> Attributes. Created attribute with slug "versione" and terms with slug "cartaceo" and "digitale". I've applied the attributes to a product to test using attributes/variations tab inside the product edit page. Added to cart (first been empty) but it doesn't work :(. When I click on the product from the cart page it gives me this link (idk if it can help) --> https://flypont.com/prodotto/voucher-a320basic-60/?attribute_pa_versione=digitale @LoicTheAztec
